# how to insert multiple option listbox choices into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, listbox

I have a form with different input fields like text field, dropdowns, and a multiselect listbox.  The multiselect listbox does not add to the database.  Please help

```
 <form action = "A.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <fieldset>

                      <p>`Job Description:
                        <select name="DutiesDesc[]" size=5 multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF1']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF2']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF2']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF3']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF3']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF4']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF4']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF5']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF5']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF6']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF6']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF7']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF7']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF8']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF8']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF9']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF9']?></option>
                            <option value="$Arow['TextF10']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF10']?></option>`
```

The following part is A.php

```
    //Check if selections were made
    if (isset($_POST['DutiesDesc']))
    {

        $SkillsArray = $_POST['DutiesDesc'];
        foreach($SkillsArray as $key =>$value )
        {
            $Sentence = join(" ",$value);
        }


    }
    $StartDate = clean($_REQUEST['StartDate']);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429450/array-posting-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do an insert query in your foreach loop.

```
foreach($SkillsArray as $key =>$value )
{
    // Insert query goes here
}
```

Also your listbox values are not parsed by PHP.

```
<option value="$Arow['TextF1']"><?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?></option>
```

should be

```
<option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?></option>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I changed the listbox value to php.  But it doesnt insert into the database.  The reason I have $sentence = join(" ",$value) inside the foreach loop is because I want to concatenate the selected options into a string and insert them along with all information from textfields into the database using one select statement.  Im fairly new to Php. I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: it seems like when the user selects options from the listbox, they dont get stored in the DutiesDesc[] array.