# Retrieve field from dynamically generated HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form in which I allow the user to dynamically clone some fields using JQuery (see [here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pmg8Z/3/)).

```
<form  name="add_treatment" method="post" action="<?php echo thisURL() ?>">
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Choose treatment</legend> 
       <select id="treatment_id" name="treatment">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
           <option>3</option>
       </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="event-set">
       <legend>Event</legend>    
       Start <input type="number" name="start"><br>
       End <input type="number" name="end">
    </fieldset>

    <div id="newFields"></div>

    <input type="button" value="+ Add event" id="addInputs" style="width: 20%"/><br><hr>

    <input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#addInputs').click(function() {
        $('#event-set').clone().appendTo('#newFields');    
    }); 
</script>
```

The form is used to display data through a "post" method. The name attributes of the different fields are used to extract them from the POST method. So I have this code at the beginning of the script:

```
<?php if($_POST){
 echo $_POST['treatment'];
 echo $_POST['start'];
 echo $_POST['end'];
} ?>
```

The problem, when I duplicate some of the fields, the all have the same name attribute. Is there a way to retrieve all the fields with the same name, or to differentiate them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    Start <input type="number" name="start[]"><br>
    End <input type="number" name="end[]">
```

instead of:

```
    Start <input type="number" name="start"><br>
    End <input type="number" name="end">
```

then you will have an array in $_POST['start'] and $_POST['end'].

See: [Array posting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429450/array-posting-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all inputs named "start" like this

```
$("input[name='start']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Start <input type="number" name="start[]"><br>
End <input type="number" name="end[]">
```

instead of:

```
Start <input type="number" name="start"><br>
End <input type="number" name="end">
```

[updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/Pmg8Z/5/)