# fill form from database then update database with more info

Tags: php, database, forms

This is probably simple but i just can't get the last little bit to work. I have a PHP/HTML form. Parts are filled in by querying the database and parts are filled in by the user. everything works except for the last $sql statement in the PHP write to database. Basically the second part of the form page retrieves a number of user stored envelopes then allows the user to input the amount to put into that envelope. I need to store that amount but there are many envelopes and i need to make sure the entered amount coresponds to the correct envelope. As you can see i am lost.

This is the main form:

```
    <form action="newpaycheck.php" method="post">
<div id="col2top">
<?php
 include 'includes/connection.php';
    echo "<select name= 'bankaccount'>";
    echo '<option value="">'.'--- Bank Account ---'.'</option>';
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT bankaccount FROM bankaccounts");
    $query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT bankaccount FROM bankaccounts");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
        echo "<option value='". $row['bankaccount']."'>".$row['bankaccount']
        .'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
?><br><br>
    Amount: <input type="text" name="paycheckamount"><br><br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="paycheckname"><br><br>
    Date: <input type="text" name="normaldate">
</div>
<div id="col2bottom">
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT envelopename, envelopebudget FROM envelopes");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Envelope</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['envelopename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['envelopebudget'] . "</td>";
    ?><td><input type="text" name="budgetamount"></td><?php;
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>  
    <input type="submit">

</div>
</form> 
</div>
```

This is what writes it all to the database:

```
<?php
//MySQL Database Connect
 include 'includes/connection.php';

// escape variables for security
$bankaccount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bankaccount']);
$paycheckamount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['paycheckamount']);
$paycheckname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['paycheckname']);
$normaldate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['normaldate']);
$budgetamount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['budgetamount']);

$sql="INSERT INTO paychecks (bankaccount, paycheckamount, paycheckname, normaldate)
VALUES ('$bankaccount','$paycheckamount','$paycheckname','$normaldate')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="ALTER TABLE envelopes ADD COLUMN $paycheckname varchar (50)";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="UPDATE envelopes SET '$paycheckname'='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: And what error do you get, or what is the result right now?

Comment: The error i am getting is: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rent'='25' WHERE 'envelopename'=''' at line 1 and the results are all good except it doesn't add the values the user inputs for each envelope.

Answer (score 1):

Column names should not be quoted. Change

```
$sql="UPDATE envelopes SET '$paycheckname'='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";
```

to

```
$sql="UPDATE envelopes SET $paycheckname='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";
```

you may use backticks if you wish

```
$sql="UPDATE envelopes SET `$paycheckname`='$budgetamount' WHERE envelopename ='$envelopename'";
```

Comment: When i take out the qoutes as you suggested i get no error but it still does not save the input values to the database for each envelope. The second while statement on the form populates multiple envelopes for which the user puts values into each one so the update statement has to update multiple rows based on the envelope name pulled from the database originally.

Comment: you never select $paycheckname eg `SELECT RENT` so it will never be displayed in your results. do you see the `1 row added` message?

Comment: to be honest your strategy of allowing users to create custom db columns seems wrong and frankly dangerous, you should create a `paychecks` table in which the rows contain different account names and then perform joins on them

Comment: The 1 record added is left over from another script i need to delete it but the $paycheckname is input by the user in the top portion of the form. i think it may be that there is nothing differentiating the envelope names since when i populate the table it is all done at once but how does it correlate an input box to that particular envelope.

Comment: you are creating a new envelope whenever a user enters a value into the `Name` field on your form `$sql="ALTER TABLE envelopes ADD COLUMN $paycheckname varchar (50)";` any kind of correlation will be near impossible with this kind of table structure. you should create a `paychecks` table in which the rows contain different account names and then perform joins on them

Comment: I have a table called envelopes thats already been created by the user. I have a table where the bank accounts have been created. What i am trying to do is i have a form that requires the user to pick an account from a drop down, enter the name of this particular paycheck, then the lower half of the screen fetches the envelope names from the envelope table and puts a text box next to each one. I want the user to put amounts in the text boxes for how much goes into each envelope then i want to post these amounts back to the database in the row for which envelope the amount was entered next to.

Comment: well, i still believe the table structure is wrong, but here's what i suggest: change `<input type="text" name="budgetamount">`  to `<input type="text" name="budgetamount[]">` now `budgetamount` will be posted back as an array rather than just posting the last input with name `budgetamount` if you're unsure as to how to handle the post of an array you should probably ask a new question. `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['budgetamount'])` will not work with an array

Comment: thank you for the response. I will have to look into the table structure further but meanwhile i will investigate more on the array.

Comment: good luck, you could always try `var_dump($_POST)` this will help to see whats going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429450/array-posting-in-php may help